# How to check validity of totp codes

Tags: java

Please help me with this task.  I'm checking the validity of totp codes; for this I need to synchronize the server time with the user time.  To do this on the client I send Date.now() in the request parameter.  And on the server I have to check the validity of the totp code based on the user’s time.  I wrote the code for this, but I'm not very good at it yet, maybe I'm doing something wrong?  Here's my code:

```
public boolean isOtpValid(String secret, String code, long epochMilli) {    TimeProvider timeProvider = new CurrentTimeProvider(epochMilli);
    CodeGenerator codeGenerator = new DefaultCodeGenerator(HashingAlgorithm.SHA256);    CodeVerifier verifier = new DefaultCodeVerifier(codeGenerator, timeProvider);
    return verifier.isValidCode(secret, code);}
```

```
public class CurrentTimeProvider implements TimeProvider {

    private final long epochMilli;

    public CurrentTimeProvider(long epochMilli) {
        this.epochMilli = epochMilli;
    }

    @Override
    public long getTime() throws TimeProviderException {
//         Instant.now().getEpochSecond()
        return Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli).getEpochSecond();
    }
}
```

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! Letting the client specify a time trivially opens up your system to replay attacks! Any stolen or phished TOTP code could be reused forever!

Comment: I guess this answer would be the most suitable cross-site dupe: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/173161

Comment: Does this mean that the client code will be valid regardless of time?

Comment: Assuming the server is synchronized/server time is correct, the client codes are valid if the client time is correct.

Answer (score 4):

**You are doing it completely wrong; what you are doing is no additional factor whatsoever and utterly insecure**.

You need to do *all* of the following aspects correct:

### Use your own time, and use a window

Yes, if the user computer's clock is not set to the same time as the server clock you have a bit of an issue, but your solution of having the client send their time is **not the solution**. The hack is trivial:

I shouldersurf a TOTP code once, like, 3 years ago. Or I simply intercept one and have a keylogger installed. Point is, I got a TOTP code once.

With your system that's good enough. I can use it *forever*, by simply sending the timestamp of when I shouldersurfed/picked up that TOTP from the logs and reuse it.

The **point** of TOTP codes is that they time out on their own, and within a short window of time (~5 minutes or so).

This is, by the way, why TOTP codes are calculated using the current time *in UTC* divided by 30 seconds; so that time zones are irrelevant. All computer systems have roughly the same UTC time, give or take a minute or two for clock skew.

#### How to do the clock right

You use a window: Every TOTP code within the window is fine. So, not just the exact 30 second window the server's clock is at, but also the 3 windows before and the 2 windows after. Or possibly even 5+5 (5 before now, 5 at/after now) - it's your choice. Bigger windows means you can deal with more clock skew but it also means a random TOTP code is more likely to be correct by accident which you don't want.

You literally write a for loop:

```
boolean totpIsCorrect(User user, int providedByUser) {
  long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 30000L;
  for (int skew = -3; skew < 3; skew++) {
    int desiredCode = user.getTotpValueAt(now + skew);
    if (desiredCode == providedByUser) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

As long as neither the server clock nor the user's clock is over a minute 'off' from the right time, this works every time. Modern hardware has fairly accurate clocks because they are network connected. Windows, Linux, and Macs all ship with network time correction enabled by default, and have for years. Smart phones have used network-corrected time since literally forever (the very first smartphones already had it, and don't even have a menu option to disable it generally).

If the server's clock truly is off, that's a bigger issue than just TOTP - your log files will be misleading, and so on. **Every security protocol in the past decade INCLUDES a rule that the server clock being off is a security leak** - so, it's *already* a crucial part of proper security hygiene to ensure the server's clock is correct.

If the user's clock is off? See later, we'll cover that in due time.

### You HAVE TO stop guessing!

A *lot* of TOTP implementations mess this up - the thing is, there are only 1 million valid TOTP codes (000000 through 999999), and, to make matters worse, about 5 to 20 of them depending on the size of the window you chose are all correct at any given time. Let's say it's, because it rounds nicely, 10 codes valid at any given time, and all you do when someone enters the wrong TOTP code is to tell them to try again, **your TOTP implementation is completely broken and adds ABSOLUTELY NOTHING to security!**

After all, all I have to do is have my hacker-server thing connect with your service, login (the point of TOTP is to protect the user *even if* their password is out on the street, so, obviously, we assume the hacker knows it), then try a random 6 digit sequence as a TOTP code.

The odds that this magically is right, is quite large: one in every 100,000 attempts will magically work. So, if it fails I just try again. It's computers - this process of logging in and trying a code takes fractions of seconds. Usually less than 10msec return time. So, to try 100,000 times **only takes about 800 seconds!!** - the TOTP protection has done absolutely nothing but slow down a hacker **for less than 15 minutes**.

The solution is to store in the database how many *wrong* TOTP attempts have been performed since the last *correct* one. And generally, the correct amount of failed TOTP attempts you should allow is **ZERO** - a single failed attempt should result in locking the TOTP code down. Which does not mean the user cannot log in anymore. Merely that they need to go through the fix-TOTP procedure (See below).

But, let's say you think that's ridiculous and you feel like you should at least give a user, say, 5 tries before you burden them down with the reset procedure.

If a user, like clockwork, logs in when they arrive at work in the morning and after lunch too, that's 2 times I know the user will log in successfully with TOTP. I can write a script that just tries 5 random things in the late morning and another 5 after lunch. Because I know the user will reset the count, I can do this every working day. Say, 200 working days in the year, that's 2000 guesses a year. That already means it takes 'just' 50 years on average to hack an account, which sounds large but is within one human lifetime. But now imagine I have managed to get the password credentials of 200 of your users, because they were dumb enough to use `iloveyou` or some other very common password. They are always there; part of the point of TOTP is to mitigate boneheaded password choices somewhat.

Now it only takes me 3 months to completely invisibly hack 1 of those 200 accounts.

#### Stopping 'guessing' correctly

1. Never even check TOTP unless the user's user/pass combination is correct. This is 'freeing' - you no longer have to worry about denial of service: If a hacker knows a user's password but not their TOTP secret, then it is **completely correct that lock that account down and let that user know** - after all, their password is out on the street! Contrast to locking accounts down on repeated failed user/pass combos: Then I can just annoy you by writing a script that tries random passwords, forcing you to deal with endless lockdowns.
2. Store in the database how many failed attempts.
3. If more than X (and I suggest X should be 0) failed attempts, a user can log in just fine, but via TOTP recovery. And make sure to list, on that page, exactly when someone failed before, including a link to report to system security if they do not recognize this attempt. Now your users can tell a hacker is guessing TOTPs just waiting to get lucky.

### Do not rely on outside sources

Very commonly tutorials about TOTP use `https://charts.google.com/qr?` or simila to generate the QR code. This should be obvious, **but do not send a shared secret to a third party, DUH!** - you do not do this. Find a library to let your own server generate the TOTP image. In java this is trivial - the zxing library can do it, it's 3 lines of code and a tiny dependency.

### Be nice to the user

TOTP and security is hard enough. Don't just tell users "That did not work". Instead, **if** it is safe to do so, provide details. The problem with TOTP is, we can't be very 'nice' because a hacker can be hacking right along. We need to do something about that 1-in-100,000 chance, because that's way too low: We can't 'help' the user by giving them info such as 'your phone's clock is skewed' because that would help the hacker too much. But if we can fix that 1/100000 ratio we can do that.

So, we fix it! With.. the recovery procedure. But first, during setup we *can* help the user, we already know that's not a hacker:

### Setup

When setting up TOTP, you always ask the user to confirm that all is working correctly by entering a TOTP code; you don't actually 'commit' and set the user account to 'now logins require TOTP' until this process is completed. For this 'verify proper configuration' event, instead of using a window of size 5 to 20, use a window **that covers about 28 entire hours** - 14 hours before and up to 14 hours after the current time. That's only 3360 TOTPs to check, your server will do that orders of magnitude faster than verifying a single password (that should use PBKDF, BCrypt, SCrypt, or some other password hash which takes millions of steps, 3360 TOTP checks is *nothing* to a server).

If the matching TOTP code is within the usual window, then, great, TOTP is now enabled.

If not, but one of the 3350 other stamps do, then **tell the user**. You know now exactly how far their clock is ahead or behind. You can literally tell the user: "The clock on your TOTP device is ahead by 55 minutes. You may have set the device to the wrong time zone and then manually corrected the clock. Consider turning on automatically adjusting your clock in your device's settings. Otherwise, check your clock's configuration, fix it, and try again".

### Recovery procedure

If a user enters the wrong code, either just because they make a typo but you have no way of knowing if that's the real user with a typo or a hacker just guessing, or, because the user's clock is off, you let them log in (username/pass) as usual, but you then tell them:

Hey, due to a failed TOTP attempt you must now recover TOTP. The failed attempt was logged at (time of every failed attempt since the last correct attempt here). If you do not recognize these timestamps, contact your system administrator immediately (and make that a link): A hacker likely has your username and password and is attempting to log into your account by guessing TOTP codes.

To recover your TOTP: Please enter 3 consecutive TOTP codes. Enter the TOTP code you see right now, then wait until the display refreshes and a new code is shown; enter that one in the second box. Wait another 30 seconds until the number refreshes again, and enter that in the third box.

A hacker guessing a TOTP is 1/100,000 odds. However, a hacker guessing a 3-consective-TOTP is more in the ballpark of 1 in **1 trillion**. (a million million million, divided by 10). While we're at it, you can apply the same 'check all 3360 codes in a 28 hour window' trick here - there's no chance this accidentally lets in a hacker that's guessing codes. Because 1 trillion divided by 3360 is still a very large number indeed.

You can now again help the user help themselves by letting them debug their own TOTP situation: You just tell them: "Ah, your clock is off by 3 hours and 42 minutes". You can let users try these 3-consecutive codes as many times as they like; add timeouts if you want but security does not demand it here. Once successful, the next time they try to log in, they get to enter just 1 code again.

Comment: _"Usually less than 10msec return time. So, to try 100,000 times only takes about 1 second!! "_ -- (a) 10ms is too short, you need to allow for network lag, so more like 50-100ms on average; (b) 10ms x 100000 = 1000 seconds, not 1 second.

Comment: If your server is in some IAAS getup such as AWS or Azure, and you fire up a server in the same locale (say, eu-central-1c), it's _less_ than 10ms. But, yes, I did mess up my order of magnitude math and will fix it.